# JPA getSingleResult did not retrieve the associated @OneToMany entites

Tags: java, jpa

As the title suggest, getSingleResult didn't retrieve the associated OneToMany entity. But here's the thing, it works after i redeploy the project (it's an JSF project btw).

Lease class:

```
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "leaseDate")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date leaseDate;
  @Column(name = "returnDate")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date returnDate;
  @Column(name = "status")
  private Integer status;
  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lease")
  private Collection<LeaseDetail> leaseDetailCollection;
```

LeaseDetail:

```
  @EmbeddedId
  protected LeaseDetailPK leaseDetailPK;
  @Column(name = "status")
  private Integer status;
  @JoinColumn(name = "bookId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Book book;
  @JoinColumn(name = "leaseId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Lease lease;
```

How i insert Lease and LeaseDetail into DB:

```
  public Lease insert(Lease lease){
    em.persist(lease);
    return lease;
  }
  
  public void insertDetail(List<LeaseDetail> details){
    for (LeaseDetail leaseDetail : details) {
      em.persist(leaseDetail);
    }
  }
```

How i fetch Lease from DB, filtered by ID:

```
  public Lease findLease(int id){ //THE PROBLEM: only retrieve associated LeaseDetail AFTER redeploying project
    try{
      return em.createNamedQuery("Lease.findById",Lease.class) //@NamedQuery(name = "Lease.findById", query = "SELECT l FROM Lease l WHERE l.id = :id")
          .setParameter("id", id)
          .getSingleResult();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

If i insert a Lease (let say Lease A) with few associated LeaseDetail, and then proceed to fetch the newly inserted Lease (Lease A) from the database, it doesn't have the associated LeaseDetail, even though the Lease it self is fully retrieved.

Now, if i redeploy the project, and then proceed to fetch Lease A, only then it have the associated LeaseDetail collection. I can't seem to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to retrieve the associated collection from the entity. You could use JOIN FETCH in the @NamedQuery.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Lease.findById", query = "SELECT l FROM Lease l JOIN FETCH l.leaseDetailCollection WHERE l.id = :id")
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the relationship `@OneToMany` is a lazy fetch. You can override the fetch type by adding `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` in the annotation.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

be careful with that in real world programming of course that could lead to you fetching a excessive amount of data from the database.

If you want to know more about lazy fetching

[https://thorben-janssen.com/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/](http://The%20default%20behavior%20of%20the%20relationship%20@OneToMany%20is%20a%20lazy%20fetch.%20You%20can%20override%20the%20fetch%20type%20with%20adding%20fetch=FetchType.EAGER%20in%20the%20annotation.%20%20%20@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)%20%20%20be%20careful%20with%20that%20in%20real%20world%20programming%20of%20course%20that%20could%20lead%20to%20you%20fetching%20a%20excessive%20amount%20of%20data%20from%20the%20database.%20%20%20If%20you%20want%20to%20know%20more%20about%20lazy%20fetching%20%20%20%20%20https://thorben-janssen.com/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/)